# Cant see changes in database after SaveChanges() called entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, savechanges

I have a table `Device` with only one column `UID nvarchar(128)` and here is my entity:

```
[Table( Name="Device" )]
public class Device
{
    [Key]
    public string UID { get; set; }
}
```

When I trying to insert entity and commit changes to database all is ok. But in database there are no new rows added. If I try to repeat this operation with the same UID - I get en eror

> *Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Devices'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Devices'. The duplicate key value is ...*

What's wrong?

*EDIT:*

Here is my context:

```
public class DeviceContext :  BaseDbContext, IDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity.Device> Device { get; set; }

    public new IDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class
    {
        return base.Set<T>();
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Fails `SaveChanges()` method. `BaseDbContext` is only "connectionstring layer".

```
DeviceContext context = new DeviceContext();
context.Device.Add(new Device() { UID = id });
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: please show the code that fails

Comment: ok - where do you use the `DeviceContext` - the code where you add more divices

Comment: have you checked that the value of `id` does not already exists in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says that data is already saved. So I think you are looking at wrong database. Verify connection string which is used by your `DbContext`.

BTW you can see which connection is used by watching at `context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` property in debugger.

Comment: There were two problems: first - I used DataAccessLayer in several projects - (WebUI  & WebApi [MVC4]).In WebUI I had connection string in .config - in WebApi not (I guess entityframework creates tempopary database in case when connection string is not found.thats explains why I havent got en error).second - the databases in visual designer and managment studio were different.

Comment: @AntonPutov I had same problems once, because of different debug and release configurations :) Btw if connections string is not specified, then EF do not use temporary database - it simply creates database on SQLEXPRESS server with name equal to DbContext name